# ST_Buffer() ST_SummaryStats conflict in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I created a segmented line and buffered each segment with a 4m buffer in PostGIS. After running `ST_SummaryStats()` on the `geom` element of my segmented line I get a lot of `NULL` values in my attribute table. When I run zonal statistics on the same geometry in QGIS (Raster Analysis > Zonal statistics) I get no NULL values while running GRASS `v.rast.stats` gives me  exact the same output like in PostGIS, additional with the warning:

```
WARNING: Not all vector categories converted to raster. Converted 2128 of 3361.
```

Which correspondents also with the numbers of missing values in Postgis.

My code looks like this:

```
    WITH polygons AS( SELECT row_number() Over()::int AS id, ST_Buffer(ST_LineSubstring(geom, n/length,
      CASE
        WHEN (n+dist) < length THEN (n+dist)/length
        ELSE 1
      END),4, 'endcap=flat join=miter' ) AS the_geom
    FROM
      (
      -- Example line of length 10m
      SELECT 10.0 AS dist,
             ST_Length(geom) AS length,
             geom AS geom
      FROM <line.table> 
      ) AS subQ
    -- We cross join with a series.
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,(floor(length/dist)*dist)::int,dist::int) AS n
    )
    
    SELECT id,the_geom,
    (ST_SummaryStats(ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast,the_geom)))).max
    FROM <raster.table> join polygons on st_intersects(rast,the_geom)
    GROUP BY id,the_geom;
```

I think the error is located at the `ST_Buffer()` function which somehow throws out "incompatible" geometries for `ST_SummaryStats()`, but I cannot detect why some geometries are valid for `ST_SummaryStats()` and some invalid.

How can I solve this problem?

I am using PostGIS Version 2.3.2.

Comment: Try adding st_makevalid() around the geometry. That's the 1st thing i would if I had a hunch it might be a geom issue

Comment: Maybe try saving just that cte portion to a table and view it in QGIS just to make sure you are creating what you intend